# Image in full screen with img tag

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, background-image

I am using the `img` tag for my slider images. I need the **image to be full width and height and centered** inside its container.

My problem is, when I resize the window width, my image becomes small and its height doesn't follow the window height. I need the **same behaviour as `background-size: cover` but with the image tag**.

```
background: url(../images/slider/002.jpg) center center;
background-size: cover;
```

If I make the image a background, everything works fine, but the slider will not. I need to use the `<img>` tag.
Here is my [example](https://jsfiddle.net/XW2un/1/).

Comment: try to set min-height using media query for other devices

Comment: i need to use image tag itself.

Comment: Did you want something like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ECJmH

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There are several ways to make an **image cover a div** with the image tag, the simplest is to use the [object-fit property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit?v=control) like this :

```css
html,body{
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
}
img{
  display:block;
  width:100%; 
  height:100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/5NK0H1e.jpg" alt="">
```

The browser support is good for object-fit (see [canIuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit)) but if you need to support more browsers (like IE), you can use this technique to **center an image fullscreen image with the `<img>` tag** :

- vertical and horizontal centering with absolute positioning, negative top, bottom, left and right values combined with `margin:auto;`
- **image always covers viewport** with 100% `min-height` and `min-width`

**[DEMO :](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Yq5KR/135/)**

```css
html,body{
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
img{
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    position:absolute;
    top:-100%; bottom:-100%;
    left:-100%; right:-100%;
    margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/5NK0H1e.jpg" alt="">
```

Comment: is there any option to make that image center with js or css?

Comment: Yes it is, you can use css transform and margin-left for this:
http://jsfiddle.net/Yq5KR/32/

Comment: @wesleycoder or you can use absolute positioning with negative top/bottom/left/right values combined with `margin:auto;` http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Yq5KR/33/

Comment: Works great with small images. Oddly enough large images are not being downscaled but displayed way to large.

Comment: @ldwg I added another technique that solves the issue with the large images with the `object-fit` property.

Comment: The IE compatible solution doesn't work on mobile (try it with devtools). Here is a working alternative: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/#article-header-id-2